# Mapping object with _id field in spring data mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mapping

i got a problem when mapping to _id field on my class Item. My data on mongodb has the following structure :

```
         {"_id" :{ "date" : { "$date" : "2013-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"} , 
                    "hour" : 0.0 ,  "a" : 681473.0 , "b" : "3814"}
                 }
         "value": 1 "}
```

so i want to map this data structure to an class. So i create my class with structure below:

```
    public class Item {
    @Id
    InternalItem _id;
    int value;
   }
```

with InternalItem class is somethings looks like:

```
   public class InternalItem {

        Date date;
        Double hour;
        Double a;
        String b;
   }
```

but when i do the query, the result in GroupByResult has null value in _id field of my Item class, looks like it can't map to _id field in this situation. So how could i map this, please tell me, thanks you guy alot

Answer (score 0):

is Field "_id" not reserved for ObjectId Value of document ?

For Example: 
   { '_id': ObjectId('jgh789tzkljghg973tgligu'), ......

Comment: yes, in this structure, there is not ObjectId field like usual mongodb structure, i think that's also the problem why i can't map, however, whether there is a solution for this or not ?

Comment: I think you should change the name of the property and your problem will eventually disappear .

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean to change the name property, could you give more details ?